# Web fonts not displaying correctly in some browsers

Tags: browser, fonts, web

When I view certain sites I get text that looks outlined like the image below:

[image: Outlined fonts]

The first font in the font-family css for this is helvetica neue. I'm on a windows machine and don't have this font, but do have arial which is listed as a font.

This is happening in Chrome and Firefox, both upto date. Doesn't happen in IE9.

I haven't a clue what to Google for so posting here hoping someone has seen this before.

Comment: could you post your css file?

Comment: this isn't from my website. This happens on numerous websites and I just happened to post this example. I tried disabling some of the css rules on the text and found that disabling font-weight: bolder; seems to be fixing the issue

Comment: hmm, yeah sorry I missed that first line. This seems to be a Helvetica issue on your system. Chrome and firefox seem to look for ALL versions of Helvetica on your system. If it finds conflicting versions, it will display it like this. Try deleting all Helvetica fonts except for Helvetica Lt Std & Helvetica Neue Lt Std (linotype's)

Comment: MaxMackie is right. I deleted Helvetica font from my pc and all is well. Good job I'm not one of those designer weirdos who needs that font

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a Helvetica issue on your system. Chrome and firefox seem to look for ALL versions of Helvetica on your system. If it finds conflicting versions, it will display it like this. Try deleting all Helvetica fonts except for Helvetica Lt Std & Helvetica Neue Lt Std (linotype's)