# Fonts displaying incorrectly in all web browsers (Win 7)

Tags: windows-7, firefox, google-chrome, browser, fonts

I'm running into an odd issue in Windows 7 in which fonts are displaying incorrectly in IE, Firefox, and Chrome. I haven't made any browser specific changes to fonts, and I've tried restoring the default settings both in the browsers and in the Windows Fonts Control Panel. An odd font is displaying and ASCII is being displayed for special characters such as ', &, etc.

I can't seem to find any settings in Windows Control Panels or within the browsers themselves to fix this issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: There are a few good answers on this site already for weird font display in web browsers. Usually it is a font that got mixed into the Win7s Special new layered fonts.  http://superuser.com/questions/307085/web-fonts-not-displaying-correctly-in-some-browsers?rq=1 If you have a normal machine, it can be quick to just compare what should be there in the windows fonts, and delete the extra/repeat/wrong one.

Comment: @user275922 A screenshot would help. You do not have enough reputation yet to put pictures in your post, but if you just put it e.g. on imgur.com and edit the link into your question, somebody else will move the actual picture in.

Answer (score 0):

I've been fighting this for weeks.  I did just about everything anybody suggested short of a system restore or downloading some sketchy "*.dll" fix.  I Cleared Caches did font overrides and a bunch of other stuff that did not work.  I went through my font list one at a time.  I removed duplicate arial fonts (i had Arial black in there a couple of times.) As soon as I restarted chrome an/or firefox my problems were solved.  I hope this post saves someone some frustration.