# Windows displaying shapes and lines instead of Letters

Tags: windows, browser, fonts, special-characters

Windows is not displaying certain fonts for some reason. Any idea how to fix this ??
[image: Preview]

To read this text, I have to copy it and paste on notepad.
[image: Text]

Comment: Related : [1](https://superuser.com/q/307085/152004)

Comment: @Rubén I tried doing that, but its still the same

Comment: I suggest you to add more details like the Windows version as well the name and version of the web browser that you are using.